# I need to write two Java programs, one which uses the methods of the other. How do I proceed according to the first program I wrote?

Tags: java, object, methods, constructor

```
import java.util.*;
 public class RegisterUI
  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   `
      //creating objects of class CashRegister
        CashRegister runningTotal = new CashRegister(); 
        CashRegister amountTendered = new CashRegister();
        CashRegister changeDue = new CashRegister();
        Scanner keyboard_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int selection = keyboard_input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Cash Register");
        System.out.println("Running total: R" + runningTotal.total(keyboard_input.nextDouble()));
        System.out.println("1. Ring up item.");
        System.out.println("2. Enter amount tendered.");
        System.out.println("3. New transaction.");
        System.out.println("4. Quit");
        while (selection != 4)
        {
            if (selection == 4)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (selection == 1)
            {
```

//getting input from CashRegister program

### Is it correct to use ' keyboard_input.nextDouble()' to get input for runningTotal?

```
                System.out.println("Enter amount:");
                runningTotal.total(keyboard_input.nextDouble());
                System.out.println("Running total: R" + runningTotal.total(keyboard_input.nextDouble()));
                // code to get amount from CashRegister
            }
            if (selection == 2)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter amount:");
                amountTendered.tender(keyboard_input.nextDouble());
                System.out.println("Running total: R" + runningTotal.total(keyboard_input.nextDouble()));
                System.out.println("Amount tendered: R" + amountTendered.tender(keyboard_input.nextDouble()));
                System.out.println("Change due: R" + changeDue.change());
            }
            if (selection == 3)
            {
                System.out.println("Running total: R" + runningTotal.total(keyboard_input.nextDouble()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

So far, I have written one program, but I need the CashRegister program to test it.

What methods can I create to be able to input the values, and carry out calculations?

The whole question:

```
The Acme cash register is a simple device that is used in commerce to calculate sales and change due. (Actually, strictly speaking, it's not a register at all since it does not record sales. It just assists with the calculations.)
The device supports customer transactions in the following way:
 Ready to ring up a customer's purchases, the running total is initially zero.
 As the operative enters the price of each item the running total is updated.
 Once the final item has been added, requesting payment, the operator may enter the amount tendered. This causes the cash drawer to open along with the calculation of the change that is due.
 Having received payment and obtained change as required, closing the cash drawer serves to complete the transaction, setting the running total, amount tendered and change due back to zero.
 The running total may be examined at any point.
 A transaction can be cancelled at any point. All values stored by the register revert to zero.
An Acme cash register simulator is required. Here is sample I/O for the program:
Cash Register
Running total: R0.00
1. Ring up item.
2. Enter amount tendered.
3. New transaction.
4. Quit
1
Enter amount:
34.50
Running total: R34.50
1. Ring up item.
2. Enter amount tendered.
3. New transaction.
4. Quit
2
CONTINUED
Enter amount:
50
Running total: R34.50
Amount tendered: R50.00
Change due: R15.50
1. Ring up item.
2. Enter amount tendered.
3. New transaction.
4. Quit
3
Running total: R0.00
1. Ring up item.
2. Enter amount tendered.
3. New transaction.
4. Quit
4
Design and implement a CashRegister class that models Acme cash register function, and then write a program called RegisterUI that uses a CashRegister object, providing I/O.
Use the design of the meterology program of question 3 to guide you:
The CashRegister class should contain methods for each register function.
The RegisterUI class should be responsible for creating a CashRegister object,
obtaining user input, calling the CashRegister object’s methods, and printing results.
The CashRegister class should NOT contain any print statements.
```

Comment: I think nobody understands what you are asking...

Comment: I edited the question and posted the whole question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the title question, you can export your first project as .jar and then import it in your second project.

```
Right click on first project -> Export -> jar
Right click on second project ->import
```

and you could use something like

```
private String getInput(String description) {
System.out.print(description + ": ");
String input = null;

InputStreamReader stream = null;
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    // Open a stream to stdin
    stream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);

    // Create a buffered reader to stdin
    reader = new BufferedReader(stream);

    // Try to read the string
    input = reader.readLine();           
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 

return input;}
```

to read input from keybord and then just convert the String you entered to Double or any other type you need